# how to use removeclass() function in Jquery to disable the CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to remove the styling(class="textinput") made for this div using Jquery. This textinput class is being used for other div as well, meaning to say i would only like to textinput functionality for the class readonly.

Lets have two scenarios:
1)

```
<div class="textinput boxshadow readonly">
<input id="id_lastname" class="boxshadowinset yellowbackground" type="text" maxlength="255" value="Language" name="lastname" readonly="readonly" title="This field is read-only">
</div>
```

2)

```
<div class="readonly">
<div class="textinput boxshadow">
<input id="id_lastname" class="boxshadowinset yellowbackground" type="text" maxlength="255" value="Language" name="lastname" readonly="readonly" title="This field is read-only">
</div>
```

I tried this:

```
$('div:readonly').removeclass('textinput');
```

It didn't work...

How different will the solutions be for the two scenarios?

Any suggestions on how to go about doing this? Need some guidance on solving this...

Comment: -1 because "it didn't work" is "not useful". Also, there are numerous examples ..

Comment: Should the `textinput` class be removed from the second `div` in example 2), or do you want it to be kept intact in that case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class qualifier is `.` and not `:`. Also as @Cupidvogel writes, it should be `removeClass`.

```
$('div.readonly').removeClass('textinput');
```

#### Edit

With the new requirement to handle nested cases too:

```
$('div.readonly, div.readonly div.textinput').removeClass('textinput');
```

This will match both readonly divs that have the `textinput` class and any divs with `texinput` class that are contained in a div with `readonly` class.

Comment: i edited the question slightly... how will the answer differ?

Comment: Yes, I saw that you edited so that the answer is now not completely valid any more. Please don't do edits that change the meaning/scope of a question after it has been posted. If you need more information, post another question.

Answer (score 2):

The function is `removeClass()`, not `removeclass()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try selector with `.`: $('div.readonly')

Answer (score 0):

The class qualifier is `.` and not `:`.
also the function is removeClass and not remove class..

```
$('div.readonly').removeClass('textinput');
```